# "Tear(drop)" synonyms

Tags: single-word-requests, synonyms, poetry, archaicisms, poetic

I've been looking for the synonyms (especially poetic ones) referring to the nouns "tear" and "tear-drop". Unfortunately, there wasn't much for me to find. I've found two, poetic ones - *"brine"* and *"lachryma"*. Are there some other (poetic or even archaic) synonyms?

Comment: If you live on [Arrakis](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arrakis), you might well describe someone crying as _shedding water_. I've always found that quite poetic. May not work in your context, of course. (Arrakis is a desert planet where water is extremely scant, so shedding valuable water is seen as a sign of great emotion.)

Answer (score 1):

***Waterworks*** is used as a slang term which means *tears* or *the source of tears*.

Though, it is usually used in the idiom ***turn on the waterworks*** which means to start crying (especially for a dramatic effect).

<sub>**Note:** *Waterworks* is also used as a humorous euphemism for the urinary system in British English, so use the word with caution.</sub>